# How can I aggregate data from separated databases in more efficient way?

Tags: database

Firstm I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.3`.
I'm solving the problem which is to retrieve a data from a separated databases and to render it into a web page. The web project is on the `Java` (`JSF 1.2`). Presently that particular feature's implemented by using `dblink` query, which retrieves a tables from a separated databases and `FULL OUTER JOIN` these tables. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

UPD: I need to retrieve that data in a real time, after `http`-request comes from the client.

UPDD: The page to render contains 100-300 records each of them consist of 10-15 varchar(30), bigint, numeric or integer fields. Correspondingly I need to retrieve 100-300 records per request. The thing is erlier it worked in the way to retrieve all data from the `sql`-server via `hibernate`'s `criteria.list()` with futher sorting, paging etc... . By now I've done that to retrieve the only data which is need to render. I've written native `sql`-query for that but it works even more slowly... It seems I need another way to solve that.

Comment: Do you need the data from the separated database in realtime? Or is it sufficient to grab it once a day or so?

Comment: @Falcon Yes, I do. I've updated my Q.

Comment: How many records do you fetch at a time?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @Falcon Updated.

Comment: @gnat Could you look at my updated question?